# Django filterset - one to many query

Tags: python, django-models, django-queryset

I have a one to many relationship modelled as follows:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField....
    ...

class Contract(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    type = models.IntegerField()
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    ...
```

I want to construct an efficient queryset that returns all clients whose latest (ie the one with the most recent start date) contract.type is equal to 5.

I am afraid I am floundering around trying to resolve this one.

Can anyone help?

If its not possible, then I am considering adding a field to Client that is a one to one relationship to the latest Contract and maintaining this every time the contracts are modified. I can then simply use that field for searching.

In the end I went with the following, if this can be optimised then please let me know - ta.

```
   # this function is called by django-filter
   # its purpose is to remove any clients where the contract with the most recent start date
   # does not have a type that matches the value parameter
   def filter_contract_type(self, queryset, name, value):
       # for each client get the contract with the latest start date
       # if that contract has a type that matches the value parameter, then hold on to the pk of its parent
       # finally strip out any clients that are not in this list, from the queryset django-filter passed in and then return it
       client_ids = []
       value = int(value)
       for client in queryset:
           con = Contract.objects.filter(client=client).order_by('start_date').last()
           if con is not None and con.type == value:
               client_ids.append(con.client.id)

       return queryset.filter(pk__in=client_ids)
```

Comment: `parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)` did you mean `parent = models.ForeignKey(Client)`?

Comment: What is your database backend, postgres by any chance?

Comment: Yip, sorry Ayush, I have made the necessary edit. ta

Comment: The backend db is mysql

Answer (score 0):

Sorry cuz i don't get the better way for you but you can try:

```
# Get ez list
Cs = Contract.objects.filter(type = 5).order_by(start_date)
# and run the loop to get the 5 dif cl id
cl_ids= []
num = 0
for c in Cs:
   if c.client_id not in cl_ids:
      cl_ids.append(c.client_id)
      if len(cl_ids) > 4:
          break
```